# 'lib = "/usr/lib/R/library"' is not writable" while installing R Bioconductor package

Tags: r, bioconductor

everyone!
I'm trying to install Bioconductor package "cummeRbund" and constantly fail. I've tried 
`biocLite("cummeRbund")` command with BiocInstaller enabled, `install.packages("cummeRbund")` and their variations with specified library address. The result is always

```
"Warning in install.packages(update[instlib == l, "Package"], l, contriburl = contriburl,  :
  'lib = "/usr/lib/R/library"' is not writable"
```

and r keeps offering me to use personal directory. What should I do to get rid of this pesky issue ("cummeRbund" is not the only one package that keeps failing to install)?

My specs.: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit, R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) -- "Fire Safety", Bioconductor version 3.2 (BiocInstaller 1.20.0)

Comment: It means you don't have permission to install it system wide (you need `sudo` privileges).  If you are the only user there is nothing really wrong with a personal directory.

Comment: Yes, I understand that means I have to possess root permission, and yes, I'm a solely user. But I can't call these library, if it installed in personal directory. R can't find it.

Comment: [How should I deal with “package 'xxx' is not available (for R version x.y.z)” warning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884)

Comment: @zx8754 First double check that there are no typos. Bioconductor will not tell you the package `xXx` doesn't exists, it will tell you it's not available for your version. Copy/paste names to avoid problems. Some other problems may come too, but that's the most common

Comment: @3nrique0 I am **not** asking the question, just sharing a link to FAQ post about package issues.

Answer (score 13):

It’s normal that R’s default library path is read-only for the current user. This usually means that R was installed by a different user (most commonly a sysadmin). This isn’t a problem in itself. — Just configure R to use a different library path.

To do this, set the `R_LIBS_USER` environment variable. To preserve it across shell sessions, set the value in `~/.profile` or similar.

```bash
export R_LIBS_USER=/path/to/your/r-library
```

There’s a [detailed description of this solution in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64042444/1968).

Another solution is to install software for each user separately. This especially makes sense on a non-shared system. Some package managers support installing software for the local user, without super user rights.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 0):

---

I installed R version 3.3.0 on another OS : No ``cummeRbund´´ install issues.

Got the "3.3.0" with `$ svn co https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/` ( svn ver. 69583 ).

---

[r](/questions/tagged/r)
[cummerbund](/questions/tagged/cummerbund)