# How stop RStudio from creating empty "R" folder within "/home" directory at every startup

Tags: r, rstudio, startup

After having set the path for the default working directory as well as my first (and only) project within RStudio options I wonder why RStudio keeps creating an empty folder named "R" within my "/home" directory every time it is started.

Is there any file I could delete/edit (eventually create) to stop this annoying behaviour and if so, where is it located ?

System: Linux Mint v. 19.3
Software: RStudio v. 1.3.959 / R version 3.4.4

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Comment: I just tested on R-3.5.3 on ubuntu-16.04, and it does not automatically create an `~/R/` directory. My guess is that either (1) it's part of RStudio (sorry, I don't have it installed on my ubuntu systems), or (2) there is something in your `~/.Rprofile` that is doing it. (My bet is on #1.)

Comment: What does your `.libPaths()` look like? And does it do the same thing when you run R directly rather than trough RStudio? Is there a reason you are using such an old version of R?

Comment: Is it `R` or `.R`?

Comment: @r2evans In fact, it's RStudio which creates the empty "R" while R-3.4.4 when started from command line does not. But as a total newbie to R I don't feel like managing it through command line is a valid option to me.

Comment: @itsMeInMiami Both folders are created (by RStudio). I guess the latter one has to deal with my permission granted to save crash reports.

Comment: @MrFlick When starting R alone no extra folder is created, so it's RStudio which is annoying me. I'm simply using the version of R offered within Linux Mint "Synaptic" package management. Since my current aim is to learn using R and perform rather simple things I haven't encountered any caveats caused by "old" 3-4.4 version by now.

Comment: I understand your frustration, and I don't know of a way to prevent RStudio from creating that directory. You might consider this, though: in R, when you install a package that is not included with base R, as a *user*, you do not have permission to install packages into the system library (often `/usr/lib/R` or `/usr/local/lib/R`). The only way to allow you to install packages into R is to have a directory which is writable by you. Ergo the `~/R/version` directory. If you're learning R, I almost guarantee you'll want to install a package or two.

Comment: @r2evans But that’s patently not the correct directory location. Don’t clutter the user’s home directory.

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding your point, @KonradRudolph. `?.libPaths` specifically says *"By default R_LIBS is unset, and R_LIBS_USER is set to directory ‘R/R.version$platform-library/x.y’ of the home directory"*, which to me means that `~/R/...` is the default location. It's personal preference whether this is clutter, but regardless it is the defined location.

Comment: @r2evans … and by doing so R is breaking OS convention. Because apps aren’t supposed to write there, precisely to avoid cluttering the user home. These things belong e.g. in `$XDG_DATA_HOME`. That being said, I’m less concerned with R itself, since it’s at least configurable. But RStudio arrogantly flouts this rule and writes not one, but *two* rubbish folders into the user home directory (`~/.r` and `~/.rstudio-desktop`) without any possibility of preventing this. If *only* one application did this it would be a mere aesthetic flaw but unfortunately there are many offenders.

Comment: I don't necessarily disagree with you, but ... that's been the R way for *years*, so it is "the default behavior". I agree that `XDG_DATA_HOME` makes sense. A [suggestion](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2019-May/077782.html) (May 2019) to the `r-devel` mailing list unfortunately seems to have gone unanswered. Perhaps my [prev comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63163719/how-stop-rstudio-from-creating-empty-r-folder-within-home-directory-at-ever?noredirect=1#comment111712944_63163719) should have said "the default of" instead of suggesting it is ideal.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can prevent the creation of the `R` directory — [R is configurable](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/libPaths.html) via a set of environment variables.

However, setting these correctly isn’t trivial. The first issue is that many R packages are sensitive to the R version they’re installed with. If you upgrade R and try to load the existing package, it may break. Therefore, the R package library path should be specific to the R version.

On clusters, an additional issue is that the same library path might be read by various cluster nodes that run on different architectures; this is rare, but it happens. In such cases, compiled R packages might need to be different depending on the architecture.

Consequently, in general the R library path needs to be specific both to the R version and the system architecture.

Next, even if you configure an alternative path *R will silently ignore it* if it doesn’t exist. So be sure to manually create the directory that you’ve configured.

Lastly, where to put this configuration? One option would be to put it into the [user environment file](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html), the path of which can be specified with the environment variable `R_ENVIRON_USER` — it defaults to `$HOME/.Renviron`. This isn’t ideal though, because it means the user can’t temporarily override this setting when calling R: variables in this file *override* the calling environment.

Instead, I recommend setting this in the user profile (e.g. `$HOME/.profile`). However, when you use a desktop launcher to launch your RStudio, this file won’t be read, so be sure to [edit your `*.desktop` file accordingly](https://askubuntu.com/q/144968/9287).<sup>1</sup>

So in sum, add the following to your `$HOME/.profile`:

```sh
export R_LIBS_USER=${XDG_DATA_HOME:-$HOME/.local/share}/R/%p-library/%v
```

And make sure this directory exists: re-source `~/.profile` (launching a new shell inside the current one *is not enough*), and execute

```sh
mkdir -p "$(Rscript -e 'cat(Sys.getenv("R_LIBS_USER"))')"
```

The above is using the [XDG base dir specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html), which is the de-facto standard on Linux systems.<sup>2</sup> The path is using the placeholders `%p` and `%v`. R will fill these in with the system platform and the R version (in the form `major.minor`), respectively.

If you want to use a custom R configuration file (“user profile”) and/or R environment file, I suggest setting their location in the same way, by configuring `R_PROFILE_USER` and `R_ENVIRON_USER` (since their default location, once again, is in the user home directory):

```sh
export R_PROFILE_USER=${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}/R/rprofile
export R_ENVIRON_USER=${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}/R/renviron
```

---

<sup>1</sup> I don’t have a Linux desktop system but I believe that editing the `Env` entry to the following should do it:

```
Exec=env R_LIBS_USER=${XDG_DATA_HOME:-$HOME/.local/share}/R/%p-library/%v /path/to/rstudio
```

<sup>2</sup> Other systems require different handling. On macOS, the canonical setting for the library location would be `$HOME/Library/Application Support/R/library/%v`. However, setting environment variables on macOS for GUI applications is [frustratingly complicated](https://superuser.com/q/476752/2269).

On Windows, the canonical location is `%LOCALAPPDATA%/R/library/%v`. To set this variable, use [`[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32730613/1968) in PowerShell or, when using `cmd.exe`, use [`setx`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5898197/1968).

Comment: Incidentally, the fact that this setting isn’t the default but requires ~1 A4 page of dense explanation is mildly infuriating.

Comment: Indeed, depending on your distribution, the most convenient way of making this work in Rstudio (as opposed to R started from the command line) may be to edit the `.desktop` file. On my system (which is Manjaro), I had the choice between the two miserable options of either moving `/usr/share/applications/rstudio.desktop` to `~/.local/share/applications/` or editing it in-place. Either way, replacing the current `Exec = ...` line with `Exec=env R_LIBS_USER=${XDG_DATA_HOME:-$HOME/.local/share}/R/%p-library/%v /usr/bin/rstudio-bin %F` (and making sure that folder exists like you describe), works.

Comment: This may be a slightly amateur question to ask but could I not just simply make /usr/lib/R/library writable using `chmod /usr/lib/R/library +w`? I'm the only user on my laptop

Comment: @JJGabe This is fundamentally a bad idea. First off, it compromises system security: even as the only user, you do *not* want these directories writable to the regular user account; it’s a basic malware barrier. And secondly, it’s just unnecessary. If you are the only user on the system, the default settings of a new R installation already use the correct directories without requiring any manual configuration.